# how to implement flask restful with class inheritance

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to create a little project that exists:

1. base class - animal
2. Dog and Cat that inherit from Animal

and add for each class full rest using Flask

what is the easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it using **multiple inheritence** -

```
class Dog(Resource, Animal):
    def get(self):
        pass
    def post(self):
        pass
```